# Linux/Unix Delete files from a remote list

Tags: linux, centos, rm

I want to perform:

```
rm -Rf file.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

but from a remote list, eg: domain.com/list.txt with list.txt containing the file names (file.txt, file2.txt etc etc). How can this be done?

Comment: is domain domain.com a remote http server?

Comment: try `curl` to fetch contents from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the content of domain into variable and then call that variable with rm -rf command to delete the files in the desired location

```
content=$(wget test.com/1.txt -q -O -); rm -rf $content
```